# Why is my app not able to send SMS even with requisite permissions?

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions

My app is trying to send a sms to another number. I have the requisite permission(SEND_SMS) granted by the user. The message however does not get sent.The default messaging app display the message with a "failure to send/Resend" prompt. What is the reason behind this and how do I fix this?
My code is pretty straightforward-

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneno, null, txt, null, null);
```

Note- My app operates well below the sms frequency limit
Edit : It works fine when run from an activity but fails when run from a service. What's the reasoning behind this ?

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide a [mcve], showing how you are sending the SMS and explaining what "the message while appearing in the sms window" means.

Comment: what is you device api ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui min sdk is 19 but tested on 23 and 24

Comment: @CommonsWare Done

Comment: are you sure you have a good network signal ?

Comment: do you have credit in your sim card :P

Comment: I have credit as well as a good network signal. All other messages go through instantly

Comment: please give one more permission at runtime READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: @DharmenderManral how will this help?

Comment: i tried with API 26 and 28, which throw exception during send sms, also write code inside try catch block

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158480/5919568) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be because of where the code was getting called from . I had a service (running on a seperate thread) spawn a new thread to send out the SMSs , for some reason this seemed to lead to problems. After I removed all that unnecessary complexity and have the sms sent directly from the service it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code instead:

```
Intent sInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sInt.putExtra("address", new String[]{txtMobile.getText().toString()});
sInt.putExtra("sms_body",txtMessage.getText().toString());
sInt.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
```

Make sure you have this tag in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: There is no certainty that anything vnd.android exists on the device.  Plus this would bring up an app for editing an SMS, which may not be what he wants

Comment: I need a fully automated solution that is device independent which is why I am using what I am now.